# "File contains carriage returns at end of line" error on Windows 10

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10-desktop

I'm trying to push my local branch to a fork on Github but every time I try, I get the error message "File contains carriage returns at end of line" from virtually all the files in the cloned repo, even though I didn't work on them.

Here's a screenshot of the error message. I'm using a Windows 10 in my conda environment and VS code as my code editor.

I will also point out that I'm quite new to open source contributions too.

screenshot of error message

[image: 1]

I have tried `git config --global core.autocrlf` but nothing happened. I have also deleted my fork and clone and restarted the whole process and still got the same result at the end.

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Use `git config --global core.autocrlf false` to preserve the original, LF-only newlines, then clone again.

Comment: You mean I should delete the already cloned repo in my local system, clone it afresh before executing this command?

Comment: You should run the command _first_, then delete & re-clone.